# Limiting the size of near-coherence classes in $\omega^*$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

We say that two ultrafilters in $\omega^*$ (i.e., two non-principal ultrafilters on $\omega$) are *nearly coherent* if there is a finite-to-one mapping $\varphi:\omega\to\omega$ such that $\beta\varphi$ maps one ultrafilter to the other.

$\mathsf{NCF}$ (*near coherence of ultrafilters*) is the statement that any two ultrafilters in $\omega^*$ are nearly coherent, i.e., there is only one "near-coherence class."

So under $\mathsf{NCF}$, the only near-coherence class is all of $\omega^*$ and thus has size $2^{\mathfrak c}$.

Is there an axiom (or group of axioms) which limits the size of near-coherence classes? Specifically, is it consistent that all near-coherence classes in $\omega^*$ have size $\mathfrak c$?

Comment: That's not a great notation. $\omega^*$ often denotes the inverse order on $\omega$ (i.e. the order type of the negative integers).  Is this a common notation?

Comment: It's pretty standard, Asaf.